# Historical price data for Cardano native assets

Tags: native-assets

Does anyone know where I can get historical price data for Cardano native assets? Data that can subsequently be used for data analysis and visualization. Something similar to what taptools is using highs, lows, pct change, etc.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

i think you are out of luck with this one

only way to do this from the start of smart contracts and accurately would be to parse dex transactions on the blockchain

the good thing is there aren't that many dex's, especially in the early days, unfortunately it'll likely require collaboration with some dexes to pull it off

imho the only viable solution for your use case is to stick with taptools data along with additional feeds from coinmarketcap for the handful of native tokens that are on there